# Grinder: Not able to set External editor

Tags: jython, grinder

[image]

Find the above attached image file and any body know idea about this issue let me post in here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check File->Options->Script Editor settings and restore it to default if you modified anything. Refer attached image